# access via a deployment key is read-only

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.

I have an SSH key and I have added it to my account but whenever I push in sourcetree I get the error above. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It's likely the server configuration that's explicitly locking you out.  Not much we mere morals can do except either talk to someone that has the appropriate adminstrative access level to get your key added to the repository.

Comment: Thats fair enough, I have just used https to clone in sourcetree and ive got that working now so hopefully fingers crossed when I set my team up today It will go smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add your public key to the **ACCOUNT** ssh keys option, not to the **REPOSITORY**.